# Android ImageButton, get ImageResource with ViewPager layout

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I'm currently learning some Android and developping my first App. I use a ViewPager which contains an ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/favourite_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="onClickFav"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/heart" />
```

In my adapter for the ViewPager I tried follow onClick method:

```
private boolean nofav = true;

public void onClickFav(View v) {
        ImageButton favouriteButton = (ImageButton) v;

        if (nofav) {
            favouriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);

            Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "Woah, new favourite!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            nofav = false;
        } else {
            favouriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);

            Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "No favourite anymore...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            nofav = true;
        }
    }
```

When I click the ImageButton it changes the image. The problem is: I click the button on one view (heart_red after click) and swipe to the right (currently heart). On the new view I click the heart ImageButton. Then the ImageButton should become heart_red, instead it sets the ImageButton again to heart with message "No favourite anymore...". Reason: it is still stored

```
nofav = false;
```

So my question is. How can I get the current ImageResource of a view? With this information I could set nofav variable with every new view.

Maybe someone has also a better idea how to deal with that. Thank you!

**SOLUTION** - Veneets idea with Tag works perfect for me. Just added the Message Toast.

```
public void onClickFav(View v) {
        ImageButton favouriteButton = (ImageButton) v;

        Boolean isFav = favouriteButton.getTag() == null ? Boolean.FALSE : (Boolean) favouriteButton.getTag();

        favouriteButton.setImageResource(isFav ? R.drawable.heart : R.drawable.heart_red);

        if (isFav) {
            Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "No favourite anymore...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "Woah, new favourite!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        favouriteButton.setTag(!isFav);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain the favourite state of `ImageButton` using tags:

```
public void onClickFav(View v) {
        ImageButton favouriteButton = (ImageButton) v;

        // Assuming default is false
        Boolean isFav = favouriteButton.getTag() == null ? Boolean.FALSE : (Boolean) favouriteButton.getTag();

        favouriteButton.setImageResource(isFav ? R.drawable.heart : R.drawable.heart_red);
        favouriteButton.setTag(!isFav);
    }
```